# Adding ChakraProvider to index.js displays blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

Here is my index.js . I am using Chakra UI for the upcoming project as well as I have installed the library. In chakra UI documentation it is given as:

**2. Provider Setup#
After installing Chakra UI, you need to set up the ChakraProvider at the root of your application. This can be either in your index.jsx or index.tsx
Put in the following code:**

```
import * as React from 'react'

// 1. import `ChakraProvider` component
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react'

function App() {
  // 2. Wrap ChakraProvider at the root of your app
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <App />
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}
```

Here is my index.js . It renders blank page :(
Please help me with this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider>
      <App />
    </ChakraProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've solved this already, but you should either downgrade your chakra UI to version 1 or upgrade to React 18.

Following Chakra UI's docs automatically installs version 2 for you, which only works on React 18 without being backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced the same issue. However, after reading about it, I discovered that the problem might have been caused by using React 18 in combination with `<StrictMode />` and other packages.

After updating to the latest versions of said packages, the issue was resolved for me.